# Can Fishers test of proportion be non significant by p value and be signficant by logistic regression

Tags: regression, fishers-exact-test

The proportion in one arm achieving an outcome is 101 out of 1152
The proportion in a second arm achieving an outcome is 123 out of 1155

Baseline variables predicting this outcome are available as medians and means

Comment: Well, for one thing, you can't account for numeric baseline variables with Fisher's test. Also, why use Fisher's exact test with such large n?

Comment: Does this thread https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259635/what-is-the-difference-using-a-fishers-exact-test-vs-a-logistic-regression-for  answer your question?

Comment: It does answer the question somewhat.  I found this link to provide a better answer for me.  https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/chi-square-test-vs-logistic-regression-is-a-fancier-test-better/